# sending email (using gmail SMTP) from windows 7 server

Tags: c#, email, iis, smtp, gmail

There are many threads related to this, and my C# code is below:

```
public const string REGISTRATION_SMTP_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com ";
public const int REGISTRATION_SMTP_PORT = 465;
public const string REGISTRATION_SMTP_LOGIN = "-----@gmail.com";
public const string REGISTRATION_SMTP_PASSWORD = "----";

// send the email
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = CommonCode.REGISTRATION_SMTP_HOST;
smtp.Port = CommonCode.REGISTRATION_SMTP_PORT;
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(CommonCode.REGISTRATION_SMTP_LOGIN,CommonCode.REGISTRATION_SMTP_PASSWORD);
smtp.Timeout = 300000;
smtp.Send(mm);
```

Running the web application locally from our development Windows 7 boxes, the emails are sent successfully (using port 587).  So our gmail credentials are good.

However, when we deploy the application to our server, the gmail SMTP server is failing to respond.  We have tried ports 465, 587, and 25...same result.

On the server, we have temporarily turned off Windows Firewall.

From the command line on the server, I can telnet into smpt.gmail.com 25 (but not 587 or 465).

The server's IIS SMTP settings are identical to our local workstations.

We have read every post related to this and nothing seems to be working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your firewall blocking those ports from outgoing?  Many times network admins will set up the servers on a separate subnet from the PC's and assign different rules on the firewall.  This is where I would start.

Comment: It wont let me edit my comment, but I just saw your line about Windows Firewall.  Note that I am talking about the actual firewall presumably protecting your corporate network.  If it is Cisco and you have admin access to it, I can help you create a rule to open the ports (if you want to open them.)

Comment: @Evanlewis - Thank you for your comments, we are checking with our hos t.  Will update when we find out.

Comment: @Evanlewis - Update: We were able to solve the issue by Opening the local security policies > IP security policies on local computer > Right click on "packet filter" and click "unassign".

This worked for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were able to solve the issue by opening the local security policies > IP security policies on local computer > Right click on "packet filter" and click "unassign".

This worked for us.

Although this might not be secure.  We will look into security to figure out how we can open specific ports on our server.

Comment: tried playing with local and external firewall for ages before I found this - this is what worked in then end for me